# Change ExpanderHeader background color while hovering mouse Winui 2.x UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, winui

How to change ExpanderHeader background color while hovering mouse in Winui 2.x?

One of the way changing background is override StaticResource

```
<StaticResource
    x:Key="ExpanderHeaderBackground"
    ResourceKey="CardBackgroundFillColorDefaultBrush" />
```

Changing from code while hovering does not give any results:

```
        private void Expander_PointerEntered(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var expander = sender as Expander;
            expander.Resources["ExpanderHeaderBackground"] = Application.Current.Resources["ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush"];
        }

        private void Expander_PointerExited(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var expander = sender as Expander;
            expander.Resources["ExpanderHeaderBackground"] = Application.Current.Resources["CardBackgroundFillColorDefaultBrush"];
        }
```

I do not want to recreate the whole style for this control only for changing Header background.

Expander source here:
https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/blob/release/2.8/dev/Expander/Expander.xaml

Comment: `I do not want to recreate the whole style for this control only for changing Header background` This is the only way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set the `Background` property of the `ToggleButton` element in the visual tree directly:

```
private void Expander_PointerEntered(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var expander = sender as Expander;
    var toggleButton = GetChildOfType<ToggleButton>(expander);
    toggleButton.Background = Application.Current.Resources["ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush"] as Brush;
}

private void Expander_PointerExited(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var expander = sender as Expander;
    var toggleButton = GetChildOfType<ToggleButton>(expander);
    toggleButton.Background = Application.Current.Resources["CardBackgroundFillColorDefaultBrush"] as Brush;
}

private static T GetChildOfType<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
{
    if (depObj == default)
        return default;

    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
    {
        var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);

        var result = (child as T) ?? GetChildOfType<T>(child);
        if (result != default)
            return result;
    }
    return default;
}
```